# Add second line with copyright notice to watermark

Tags: watermark, copyright

I'm writing up some articles to send out to readers for proofreading and to solicit their commentary. I'm marking all pages as draft using a `watermark` with the code below:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage[margin=1.0in]{geometry}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{type1cm}
\usepackage{eso-pic}

\makeatletter
\AddToShipoutPicture{%
            \setlength{\@tempdimb}{.5\paperwidth}%
            \setlength{\@tempdimc}{.5\paperheight}%
            \setlength{\unitlength}{1pt}%
            \put(\strip@pt\@tempdimb,\strip@pt\@tempdimc){%
        \makebox(0,0){\rotatebox{58}{\textcolor[gray]{0.90}%
        {\fontsize{7cm}{7cm}\selectfont{DRAFT}
    }}}%
            }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam suscipit luctus suscipit. Vestibulum sollicitudin scelerisque sem, a suscipit nulla scelerisque eget. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Etiam ultrices mollis semper. Morbi eu purus in leo efficitur ornare. Nulla facilisi. Phasellus ut bibendum nisl, sit amet suscipit arcu. Mauris non risus non enim sollicitudin vulputate in ut erat. In nisi libero, viverra vitae tincidunt euismod, faucibus non ligula. Etiam sed lobortis tellus. Donec ultrices pellentesque orci eu viverra. Proin eget eros sem. Praesent molestie ac purus et mattis. Nullam vel hendrerit purus. Maecenas dapibus dignissim dolor, vel sagittis justo convallis ut.

Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Etiam ut neque id erat imperdiet cursus. Nulla eget ligula vel urna imperdiet pulvinar sed at arcu. Mauris a turpis sed dui viverra placerat. Pellentesque libero lorem, cursus ut rutrum id, semper sit amet arcu. Maecenas eu suscipit felis. Nulla molestie egestas efficitur. Quisque venenatis vitae tortor lacinia venenatis. Aliquam pulvinar elit sed dapibus sollicitudin. In magna diam, pellentesque ut tempor nec, euismod eget urna.

Vestibulum pretium magna sed urna tristique, quis euismod nisi volutpat. Donec quis sollicitudin lorem. Quisque suscipit at tortor id molestie. Sed scelerisque viverra rhoncus. Nunc euismod arcu elit, eu dignissim ligula egestas sed. Proin iaculis eleifend accumsan. Vivamus consectetur luctus malesuada. Suspendisse imperdiet ante a laoreet faucibus. Ut facilisis, est nec posuere varius, ipsum dolor eleifend risus, eu gravida erat purus at felis. Nunc accumsan ipsum non justo venenatis, non finibus dolor iaculis. Phasellus dignissim sem quis congue laoreet.

Integer iaculis, metus ut posuere efficitur, augue ligula aliquam est, in tempus turpis dui in massa. Vestibulum ut varius nulla, at tincidunt arcu. Cras quis magna efficitur odio faucibus dictum. Sed pretium gravida dui, id hendrerit urna malesuada quis. Ut hendrerit ut tortor ac porttitor. Fusce quis diam efficitur, condimentum ex vehicula, pretium ante. Sed felis elit, tincidunt nec vehicula vitae, venenatis sed arcu. Maecenas vel faucibus lacus.
\end{document}
```

That's working well. But what I'd like to do is add a second line to the `watermark`, one that uses a much smaller font, and that contains a copyright notice. My research and experimentation has thus far not led to a solution for introducing the line break and the smaller font on the second line. So I'd like to solicit input here on accomplishing this task. Thanks in advance and in general for such a great resource here.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `\parbox`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{eso-pic,xcolor,graphicx}
\AddToShipoutPicture{%
           \AtPageCenter{%
        \put(-100,0){\rotatebox[origin=c]{58}{\parbox[t]{7cm}{\color[gray]{0.90}%
        \scalebox{10}{DRAFT}\par
        \normalsize My copyright here
    }}}}%
}%

\begin{document}
   some text
\end{document}
```

[image]

I have used `AtPageCenter` instead of re-inventing the wheel.

Same with `background` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{background}
\backgroundsetup{
angle=58,
scale=1,
color=gray!90,
nodeanchor=east,
%position={0.5\textwidth,.5\textheight},%
contents={\parbox{5cm}{\scalebox{10}{DRAFT} \\
        \normalsize My copyright here}}
}

\begin{document}
   some text
\end{document}
```

If you want to stick to your approach, use this

```
\makeatletter
\AddToShipoutPicture{%
            \setlength{\@tempdimb}{.1\paperwidth}%
            \setlength{\@tempdimc}{.3\paperheight}%
            \setlength{\unitlength}{1pt}%
            \put(\strip@pt\@tempdimb,\strip@pt\@tempdimc){%
        \rotatebox[origin=c]{58}{%
        \parbox{6cm}{\color[gray]{0.90}%
        \fontsize{7cm}{7cm}\selectfont DRAFT\par \normalsize Copyright here \par
    }}}%
}
\makeatother
```

[image]

Comment: BTW `\makebox(0,0){` is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

None of these solutions offered above worked very well for me. I kept researching on the 'net and came up with something that gives results pretty close to what I want. Here's a MWE:

```
     \documentclass[12pt]{article}
        \usepackage{fullpage}
        \usepackage[margin=1.0in]{geometry}
        \usepackage{draftwatermark}
        \usepackage{graphicx}
        \usepackage{type1cm}
        \usepackage{eso-pic}
        \SetWatermarkText{\parbox{16cm}{%
          DRAFT \\
          \small{\textbf{Unless otherwise attributed, content of this document \textcopyright Yours truly, 2015}}} }}
        \SetWatermarkScale{1.2}
        \SetWatermarkColor[gray]{0.90}%
        \begin{document}
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam suscipit luctus suscipit. Vestibulum sollicitudin scelerisque sem, a suscipit nulla scelerisque eget. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Etiam ultrices mollis semper. Morbi eu purus in leo efficitur ornare. Nulla facilisi. Phasellus ut bibendum nisl, sit amet suscipit arcu. Mauris non risus non enim sollicitudin vulputate in ut erat. In nisi libero, viverra vitae tincidunt euismod, faucibus non ligula. Etiam sed lobortis tellus. Donec ultrices pellentesque orci eu viverra. Proin eget eros sem. Praesent molestie ac purus et mattis. Nullam vel hendrerit purus. Maecenas dapibus dignissim dolor, vel sagittis justo convallis ut.

        Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Etiam ut neque id erat imperdiet cursus. Nulla eget ligula vel urna imperdiet pulvinar sed at arcu. Mauris a turpis sed dui viverra placerat. Pellentesque libero lorem, cursus ut rutrum id, semper sit amet arcu. Maecenas eu suscipit felis. Nulla molestie egestas efficitur. Quisque venenatis vitae tortor lacinia venenatis. Aliquam pulvinar elit sed dapibus sollicitudin. In magna diam, pellentesque ut tempor nec, euismod eget urna.
        \end{document}
```

The positioning of the watermark is slightly off, protruding just a bit into the left margin and being not completely centered on the page (seems to have to do with the {16cm} bit). But that's almost unnoticeable and something I can absolutely live with.